# iptables and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, iptables

Edit: Being wiser now, this question doesn't make much sense. Unfortunately, I'm unable to delete it.

Comment: IMHO a more normal use case is where PostgreSQL is *not* visible from the outside, but only from the inside, or sometimes from a front end and/or DMZ. pg_hba.conf enables you to configure that on a netmask-level (for instance: no superuser-connections from the DMZ, but: application logins allowed , but only for database xyz. etc) BTW: one of the reasons for not allowing outside connections is to avoid DOS-attacks. This should be done at the firewall/iptables level.

Comment: Instead of marking questions as off topic can you migrate them to the stackexchange you deem they should belong in? That would be better than a question like this being returned in google results only to find it has been moderated into obscurity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apples-and-pears, to a large degree.

`iptables` is used as a firewall to keep unwanted traffic out of the local network, `pg_hba.conf` determines not only who can connect to the database system on the server, but also what connections (users to databases) are allowed and how they are authenticated.

In a typical setup, `iptables` would only filter on the internet connection, while `pg_hba.conf` applies to all traffic trying to connect to the database system, specifically also traffic on the internal network. So in practice, yes, you would combine them, but they are rally not something where you should weigh the benefits of one option to the other, they both serve their own purpose.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't stop any traffic from reaching the server, it only restricts access to its databases. Without a firewall like `iptables` someone might hack your server, change `pg_hba.conf` and access PG as superuser. They do different things so you should have both, but `iptables` is usually run on a server that acts as a network access point only, to protect the internal network from malicious external traffic.